# Populate a file or a style with jquery or php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

Our goal is to populate a `<style>` or a Styles file with php or jquery. This is because we want to know how many users select a random date.

We thought to take the data form a Div Tag:

```
<div data-id="s001" data-date="10102016" data-time="0900"></a>
```

We take with Jquery the `data-id` so we can add a class to  the `<body>`.So we can and a proper style to a List `<li>`

This is easy , but we need to write down every time the styles.

***UPDATE***

User Select a Date (`<li>`) , when they click on the date a form is populated and the `<body>` get the class.

Then we check the email, rudimentary, but was our fastest approach.

and We add the styles to the `<header>` manually.

`body.s001 li, body.s002 li { background: blue; cursor: no-drop; }`

So every time a New user come , then she/he/them will see that the date is already selected.

sample:

```js
$("#week_carousal li").click(function() {
  var dataId = $(this).attr('data-id');
  $('body').removeClass().addClass(dataId);
});
```

```css
body.s001 li {
  background: blue;
  cursor: no-drop;
}
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}
li {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0.75em;
  margin: 0.25em 0;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  /* Saf3.2+, Chrome */
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  /* FF4+ */
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  /* IE10? */
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  /* Opera 10.5+ */
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="week_carousal">
  <li data-id="s001" data-date="10102016" data-time="0900"><span>Select Class of 10 . 10 . 2016 at 9:00am</span>
  </li>

</ul>
```

But how can I add on click the style with out we needed to check every time if someone choose the date and write down the style or class manually.

thanks

Comment: I don't understand the question. If you want to know what users are doing, you should submit a form or use AJAX, and record it in a database. Style changes just happen in the client, they don't go back to the server.

Comment: Yes that would be the final approach, but the final delivery (api) will be not util 2 or 3 more weeks :( , but in the mean while , we are making the best we can to Extinguish the fire , so that was the only fast idea we came up ...

Comment: I still don't understand how changing styles has anything to do with knowing how many users choose the date.

Comment: ow , because you are looking in the front-end how many `<li>` changed colors. (Let me update my question so , I can Explain a little bit more)